# How can I recover data from 3TB Seagate GoFlex home in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a 3TB Seagate GoFlex Home, and it stopped working on me. It’s not a hard drive failure, just a software issue. It’s a Barracuda drive. I can hear the drive spin up without any knocking or unusual sounds but I can’t access any of the data.

I have a SATA to USB adapter—[Vantec CB-ISATAU2 SATA/IDE to USB 2.0 Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000J01I1G)—hooking the drive directly to my MacBook Pro but can’t figure out how to copy or recover the data.

I have tried to mount it, repair disk, and some other software but can’t get anything off of it without spending a bunch of money.

Any ideas as to how I could recover this data? I also have a Windows machine available, if that would be easier.

Comment: So I know it's not a physical hard drive failure because it spools up fine and doesn't make any abnormal sounds.  Also I have used the Seagate recovery tool, and it finds all the files fine, but you have to pay to actually recover the data.  So I'm thinking its something related to partitioning, or something similar.

Correct, I have taken the actual drive out of the case (bypassing the Home Dock) and connected directly to the computer with [these cables from Vantec](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000J01I1G?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o08_s00).  

Yes that is the model.

Comment: Is the drive formatted with an NTFS volume? MacOS NTFS support was not always there and in some distributions, it was not enabled by default. I am not a Mac user nor do you say what OS version you have, but it may be worth checking to see if you have it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If it was anything other than a Seagate 3TB I might optimistically support your rather hopeful "it's not hardware" assertion.
However... https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-reliability-stats-for-q2-2015/ & previous reports would inspire no confidence in that opinion.

This image alone is sufficient to convey the appalling fail rate on those drives...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You say you have this model drive:

- [3TB Seagate GoFlex Home](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000J01I1G)

And then you say.

> I have a SATA to USB adapter—[Vantec CB-ISATAU2 SATA/IDE to USB 2.0 Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000J01I1G)—hooking the
>   drive directly to my MacBook Pro, but can’t figure out how to copy or
>   recover the data.

I cannot speak for the actual condition of the drive itself since spinning up without making noise is *not really* the main indication of there *not* being a hardware failure. I have seen tons of drives “spin up” and “sound” perfectly “fine” that are 100% completely dead and uncoverable.

But don’t lose hope!

Checking the specs on that product page for that Vantec CB-ISATAU2 shows exactly what I suspected; key spec highlighted in bold by me for emphasis:

> - Easily Add Storage to Any System with USB
> - **Supports HDD Capacity Up to 2TB**
> - Transfer Rates Up to 480 Mbps with USB 2.0
> - Hot-Swappable: Plug and Play without Rebooting
> - Compatible Windows PC or Mac with Available USB 2.0 Port

Your problem is you have a 3TB SATA drive and that Vantec CB-ISATAU2 adapter can *only* support drives up to 2TB in size. What this boils down two is modern SATA controllers divide up into two distinct flavors; those which can only support drives 2TB in capacity or lower and those who can support drives that have a capacity of 2TB or higher. So that cable *will never* be usable for anything higher than 2TB in capacity like that Seagate drive you have. I don’t think it damaged your 3TB drive in any way, but it sure as hell won’t know how to mount it.

So if you want to invest some more money in self-recovery efforts, you should get another USB to SATA bridging device that can explicitly support drives larger than 2TB. For example, this [NewerTech Universal Drive Adapter](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/NewerTech/U3NVSPATA/) from Other World Computing clearly states it **“Supports drives up to 6.0TB (6000GB) and beyond.”** Get something like that, hook up the drive, mount it, copy the data and there you go!